Do I need additional retraining to transfer a feat from one slot to another?
Let's say my Fighter takes Sudden Charge at level 1, and at level 8 I want to learn Sudden Leap and replace Sudden Charge with something else. Can I rearrange which feats are in which level slots, to accommodate this, and would the act of rearranging feats require additional retraining?
For example, let's say all my class feats have lower level requirement than the level I learned them at. I retrain Sudden Charge. Could I slide each of my class feats down one slot, in order to replace Sudden Charge with a higher-level feat? I know that replacing Sudden Charge would require retraining, but would rearranging which slot each feat is in also require additional retraining?
Here's a concrete example, to illustrate:
Before:

Lv1: Sudden Charge
lv2: Combat Assessment (requires level 1)
Lv4: Aggressive Block (requires level 2)
Lv6: Powerful Shove (requires level 4)
Lv8: Sudden Leap (requires level 8)

After:

Lv1: Combat Assessment
Lv2: Aggressive Block
Lv4: Powerful Shove
Lv6: Shield Warden
Lv8: Sudden Leap

Bottom line: Can I freely rearrange which slots each feat is in, and make these changes with just a single retraining? Or alternatively, does rearranging a slot require additional retraining time?

Are feats in Pathfinder actually stored in 'slots' for a character?  When you gain a new feat, don't you just have a total number of feats known, and the new (or retrained) feat's prerequisites determine whether you can take it at that time?

The retraining rules in player core p.440 mention "you generally can't make choices you couldn't make when you selected the original option". So it does care about which slot each feat is in, since you can't put a feat with a level 20 requirement in a level 1 feat slot. It doesn't mention anything about what to do if level requirement is not an issue however. It's just ambiguous enough that I'm not sure if swapping slots is allowed or not.

Is there any particular reason you would need Powerful Shove (for example) to move "slots?"

@Jason_c_o because Shield Warden is a level 6 feat, and needs the level 6 slot.

No, and the process for switching is complex and difficult
The process for swapping a feat to a different slot is pretty comparable to a puzzle you might find in a computer RPG, like the Tower of Hanoi puzzle. What you want to do conceptually is very simple, but the steps to do so are far more complicated.
To summarize the rules of the puzzle:

You have to retrain each feat slot separately.
You cannot have a feat in a slot that does not meet its level requirements.
You cannot learn a feat if you do not meet its prerequisites.
You cannot at any point have duplicate feats, unless those feats explicitly say you can take the feat multiple times.

This means that you cannot just replace Sudden Charge (level 1 slot) with Shield Warden (level 6 slot) because these two feats need to go in different slots, and you can only replace feats that go in the same slot.
Nor can you replace Sudden Charge (level 1 slot) with Combat Assessment because you already know Combat Assessment in your level 2 slot. You instead must replace Combat Assessment (level 2 slot) with some other feat you don't want, so that you no longer know Combat Assessment, just so you can then re-learn Combat Assessment again in the level 1 feat slot, replacing Sudden Charge. The game does not care that you never wanted to unlearn Combat Assessment in the first place.
You must then repeat this process for each other feat you want to transfer to a different slot.
In total, at a cost of 1 week per swap, this will require SIX WEEKS of retraining to perform, with the following sequence of unlearning and retraining. Less optimal solutions to this puzzle will require even more weeks, so players less skilled at puzzle games will have a harder time.

Replace Combat Assessment (level 2 slot) with Double Slice (an irrelevant feat you don't want)
Replace Sudden Charge (level 1 slot) with Combat Assessment
Replace Aggressive Block (level 4 slot) with Exacting Strike (an irrelevant feat you don't want)
Replace Double Slice (Level 2 slot) with Aggressive Block
Replace Powerful Shove (level 6 slot) with Shield Warden
Replace Exacting Strike (level 4 slot) with Powerful Shove

You might ask, wouldn't it be a more optimal solution to this puzzle to replace feats going from high level to low level, as that would eliminate the need for intermediate placeholder feats, thereby reducing the number of swaps to equal the number of feats shifted, rather than twice the number of feats shifted. The problem with that is that if there are any feats which have another feat as a prerequisite, and that prerequisite is in an adjacent slot, you cannot relearn the high-level feat without relearning its low-level prerequisite first. You therefore must relearn the feats from low level slot to high level slot, rather than high level slot to low level slot, thereby doubling the number of required swaps.
In the worst-case scenario, where you wanted to replace a level 1 feat with a level 20 feat, and shift all the other feats down one slot, it would require at least 20 weeks of retraining, assuming you performed the swaps correctly.

I don't understand what your point is. The example is one in which you want to remove the feat in the level 1 feat slot, shift all the other feats down a slot, and place a feat in the level 6 slot. How would you propose accomplishing that without rearranging all the feats?

And you can say that this situation is unlikely, but that's simply disingenuous. I've been a situation like this with pretty much every character I've played, because there's so many feats that are basically an upgraded version of a lower-level feat. You can't just replace the lower-level  feat with the higher-level one. You have to shift the feats down.

-1. Interesting thought, but step 6 is invalid. You can't retrain Powerful Shove into your level 4 slot, because you didn't qualify for it when you originally selected a feat for that slot. You would have needed to select Aggressive Block (or Brutish Shove) earlier.

@indigochild I did. Did you not see step 4 where I retrain Aggressive Block into the level 2 slot?

Retraining doesn't help. You need to have qualified for it when you first gained that feat slot. When you first gained the level 4 slot, you did not qualify for Powerful Shove. No matter what retraining you do, you can never put Powerful Shove there.

No, that's silly. You're essentially arguing that it's impossible to retrain feat chains.  There's nothing in the rules to suggest that. Please, don't be disingenuous.

@indigochild Also, that absurd paradigm would forbid things like undoing a retraining (you already knew the feat at that level originally, so you can't take a duplicate feat, even though it isn't a duplicate anymore).  It would also contradict p.440 under Skills, which says to use the level you reassign skill increases to determine feat prerequisites.

It's in the Core Rulebook on page 481. "...you generally can't make choices you couldn't make when you selected the original option..."  You may run your game any way you like, but RAW are that you are restricted to what was available when you first got the feat slot.

@indigochild Yes, and by retraining you are reselecting that option, which changes what you can pick down the line.

That's not what "original" means.

Yes it is. The feat you're replacing is the original feat.

Each feat is retrained separately.
The main restriction to retraining (without getting into the weeds of extreme retraining) is previous prerequisites. You mention this in the comments as clarification:

When retraining, you generally can't make choices you couldn't make when you selected the original option. For instance, you can't replace a skill feat you chose at 2nd level for a 4th-level one, or for one that requires prerequisites you didn't meet at the time you took the original feat. (Player Core pg.440 - Retraining, Emphasis mine)

You couldn't retrain Aggressive Block into Powerful Shove, because you did not qualify for Powerful Shove at level 4, which was when you first took Aggressive Block. This trickles all the way down (or up).

If you cease to meet the prerequisites for an ability due to retraining, you can't use that ability. You might need to retrain several abilities in sequence in order to get all the abilities you want.

Your GM can choose to lessen the time commitment, if they so choose:

A character might need to retrain several options at once. For instance, retraining a skill increase might mean they have skill feats they can no longer use, and so they'll need to retrain those as well. You can add all this retraining time together, then reduce the total a bit to represent the cohesive nature of the retraining. (Gm Core pg.50 - Time)


I figured it would be something ridiculous and convoluted. Never anything straightforward in Pathfinder.

You're suggesting that a character can be in a situation where they need to spend weeks "retraining" to accomplish absolutely nothing, and ending up with the same set of abilities before retraining as after. The character in the story is "Retraining", purely in order to satisfy the game's meta-bookkeeping system even though they are learning absolutely nothing new. You seriously don't think there's anything convoluted about such a complicated arbitrary layer of abstraction?

@Strill Retraining doesn't really take into account the player that didn't plan ahead. It's meant to replace one or two things to something different. Also, you're trying to game the system by retraining later feats earlier in the  character build. Of course it's not meant for that.

How in the world is it gaming the system??? I'm replacing one feat with another, but the system is too convoluted and bureaucratic to support that.

You literally just said I can't do that.

@I'd suggest re-reading, then. If you want to replace a feat with another you qualified for at the time, you can. If you want to replace it with a feat of a higher level that you didn't qualify for, you can't. To move them around, each replacement has to have had its prereqs met, and the whole process takes in-game time proportional to the number of changes.

Can you replace a feat with a duplicate copy of a feat you already have?

Replacing a feat with a duplicate is the only way to swap a chain of feats down a level slot while still maintaining feat prerequisites at each step. In fact, if duplicates are not allowed, it will double the number of swaps required to shift each feat down, as you'll need to swap each feat with an intermediate feat you don't want before you can put the original feat in the slot you wanted to begin with.  How can you think this isn't convoluted?

@If you believe the rules work differently, submit an answer. It's not convoluted because it's quite easy to grasp. You're just not happy with the result. I'm not interested in arguing in comments. If you disagree, submit an answer.

I  downvoted your answer because it's incorrect in a couple regards. You cannot cascade the swaps down from high level to low level. Only up from low level to high level, because you cannot learn a feat without its prerequisites. That means that if you need to shift a feat chain, relearning from high level to low level is not possible because you would be learning the end of the feat chain potentially without the feat chain's prerequisites.
Furthermore, cascading also doesn't work because you would at some points in the retraining process end up  with duplicate feats, which isn't allowed.

I would recommend you give an example of the sequence of swaps you would use to retrain the feats without at any point violating one of the retraining rules.
